# Rigorously justifying asymptotic behavior of solution of nonautonomous linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

In my research, I encountered a relatively simple second order non-autonomous linear ODE
$$cy'-y''+g(x)y=0,$$
of which I know that a bounded nontrivial solution $u$ exists. Here $g$ is a sufficiently smooth function for which $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=g_+>0$. I am interested in the asymptotic behavior of this solution $u$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. We consider the 'limiting ODE'
$$cy'-y''+g_+y=0,$$
which has general solution
$$y=c_1e^{\left(\frac{c}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4}+g_+}\right)x}+c_2e^{\left(\frac{c}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4}+g_+}\right)x}.$$
Since only one of these exponentials is bounded as $x\rightarrow\infty$, it makes sense, at least intuitively, that
$$u\sim c_2e^{\left(\frac{c}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4}+g_+}\right)x}\text{ as }x\rightarrow\infty$$
for some constant $c_2$. However, I am not sure how to make this asymptotic behavior rigorous. Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance.